# SSIS Script Component

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, ssis

I found this piece of code which works fine for my input (a string of CSV). The package runs fine, but instead of getting 5 columns of output, I only get 2 columns. I added additional columns in the Script Component and also changed their data types to the suitable ones. The input is 643492,PV STRIP 1X1 UTILITY UP,,67.5,393446. Out of this entire string, I only get 643492 in one column and PV STRIP 1X1 UTILITY UP in another. Rest of the string comes out blank no idea why. Experts kindly help. I dont know anything about .net and I am new to SQL Server as well.

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    Dim strRow As String
    Dim strColSeperator As String
    Dim rowValues As String()
    strRow = Row.Line.ToString()
    If strRow.Contains(",") Then
        strColSeperator = (",")
    ElseIf strRow.Contains(";") Then
        strColSeperator = ";"
    End If

    rowValues = Row.Line.Split(CChar(strColSeperator))
    Row.Code = rowValues.GetValue(0).ToString()
    Row.Description = rowValues.GetValue(1).ToString()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are only assigning the first two values to the buffer row. The last two lines of your code snippet is where the assignment is being made. Your `rowValues` array should contain 5 values based the `Split()` on the string you provided in your example. You can assign them using the `GetValue(index)` method. Do this for indexes 3 through 5 of your array.

The string values go like above:

```
Row.FieldName = rowValues.GetValue(0).ToString()
```

where Code is the name of the field and 0 is the zero-based index of the value in the array.

For an integer, you can do something like:

```
Row.FieldName = Convert.ToInt32(rowValues.GetValue(3))
```

You can use other `Convert` methods to convert to your desired output type.  [See MSDN for reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bds4fye2.aspx)

Comment: I discovered that just now. But thanks for your reply. Cheers!!